# How I can add new field in coming firebase snapshot of onWrite() firebase cloud method

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried with `set` and `setvalue()` methods. I want to add `document_id` field in coming snapshot here is my code.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { getFirestore, Timestamp, FieldValue } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = getFirestore();

exports.locationUpdateListener = functions.region('asia-south1').firestore
    .document('location/{locationId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        const data = change.after.data();
        const timeMilli = process.hrtime.bigint();
        const id = data.mobile + '_' + timeMilli;

        data.set({ 'document_id': id });//here I need to add document_id field into data.

        db.doc('history_location/' + id).set(data);
    });
```

Comment: Can you update your question with more description?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the new field to `data` it just exists in the current code. To persist the value, you will have to write it back to Firestore with something like this:

```
exports.locationUpdateListener = functions.region('asia-south1').firestore
.document('location/{locationId}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
    const data = change.after.data();
    const timeMilli = process.hrtime.bigint();
    const id = data.mobile + '_' + timeMilli;

    // 
    if (data.document_id !== id) {
        change.after.ref.update({ 'document_id': id });
    }

    db.doc('history_location/' + id).set(data);
});
```

Don't forget the condition I added, as otherwise you'll end up with an endless loop.